# Problem with the use of libraries in a ReactJS application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use a library that will allow me to implement a barcode reader on our application. For this, I must use the library in question "expo-barcode-scanner" whose doc is available here https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/
and also the react-native library.
When compiling the code I got an error like Module not found.

Here is the code that I use in the App component and which is the source of the bug:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';

export default function App() {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    setScanned(true);
    alert(`Bar code with type ${type} and data ${data} has been scanned!`);
  };

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
      }}>
      <BarCodeScanner
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
      />

      {scanned && <Button title={'Tap to Scan Again'} onPress={() => setScanned(false)} />}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Error message:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/expo-barcode-scanner/build/BarCodeScanner.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@unimodules/core' in '/var/www/html/Stop-O-gaspi/Tests-StopOgaspi/node_modules/expo-barcode-scanner/build'
```

also another message in the console which seems more significant to me:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: You haven't tagged the question as react-native, but the library you link appears to be designed for native. You may need to either edit your tags, or find a new library.

Answer (score 0):

NPM doc says: 
**Installation in bare React Native projects
For bare React Native projects, you must ensure that you have installed and configured the react-native-unimodules package before continuing.**

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-barcode-scanner => pointing to https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/react-native-unimodules

Comment: I installed the react-native-unimodules package but it still doesn't work ... I have this error now : ```Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/build/nativeEmitters.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native-web/dist/vendor/react-native/NativeEventEmitter/RCTDeviceEventEmitter' in '/var/www/html/Stop-O-gaspi/Tests-StopOgaspi/node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/build'```

Comment: Also have made the `Configure iOS` and `Configure Android` steps?

Comment: I'm using this code on a ReactJS app for the web, do I still need to configure iOS and Android?
If this is the case, I don't really see how to do it ...

Comment: I know, but it seems that we can use the react-native library in a ReactJS application.You say it is not possible?

Comment: It's depend. If you are just using a simple UI, or logical library, it's possible to cross the web, and mobile. But if there are a sensor specific lib, what would controll the bluetooth, or camera, that optimized just for mobile(`react-native`)

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean ... And if we only want to manage the desktops web cam for now and not the other devices, how could we go about it?

Comment: What you want? Web app? Desktop app?